# One form with multiple fields vs several forms doing ajax requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, forms

I have a group of invoices to send to a back end.

The requirement is to be able to send everything with a button, so I can do the following:

- Send everything as form fields name like form1_detail_text
  where form1 would be the id of the invoice, detail the part, and text the kind of field.
- I can put every invoice separated in its own form, and send them by ajax, every form success I send the next one and so on.

I did some research between some of my co-workers and many of them told me to just go with a post with all the invoices at the same time and then access every field by item id because I don't have knowledge of how many invoices are going to be sent.

But did I also read this article from a UX point of view and it keeps me thinking about it

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57599/when-should-i-use-ajax-to-submit-forms-vs-regular-page-submit

Which option could be better and why?

Comment: I really hate when people downvote without even commenting why.

Comment: Downvotes are likely because there isn't enough information on the system to be able to give a meaningful answer. Any answers would be purely opinion because of this. The mouseover for a down vote reads: "The question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, i didn't even know about that hover text